# Simple password protected page in Astro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, astrojs

I am building my own portfolio and I was looking for a way that I could have some of my pages(case studies) locked behind a static password like 1234 and then store that in the browser's cookies. how can I do that with Astro template?

**Layout.astro:**

```
---
import Basehead from "../components/Basehead.astro";
import { SITE_DESCRIPTION,SITE_TITLE } from '../consts';
const {frontmatter} = Astro.props;
---
<html>
  <head>
        <Basehead title={SITE_TITLE} description={SITE_DESCRIPTION}></Basehead>
    </head>

  <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
  <p>{frontmatter.description}</p>
  <img src={frontmatter.cover} height="200" width="200" alt="" >
  <article>
      <slot /> <!-- Markdown content is injected here -->
  </article>
</html>
```

**Page.mdx:**
My case study is here and I want to prompt users to enter the password if the `password: true`

```
---
layout: ../layouts/CaseStudyLayout.astro
title: case study post
description: the description
cover: https://framerusercontent.com/images/D5baHWHk2hVJyc1znehFavwU1I.jpeg
password: true
---

import Video from '../components/Video.astro'
export const title = 'My first MDX post'

## Background

This Markdown file creates a page at `your-domain.com/page-1/`

<Video />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this exploiting `Astro.cookies`.

```
---
import Basehead from "../components/Basehead.astro";
import { SITE_DESCRIPTION,SITE_TITLE } from '../consts';
const {frontmatter} = Astro.props;

if (frontmatter.password === true) {
  // Check cookie, I assume 1234 is your password.
  if (Astro.cookies.get('pass').value !== '1234') {
    // If not cookie is not correct, redirect to login page.
    return Astro.redirect(`/login`);
  }
}
// Otherwise page will be normally displayed.
---
<html>
...
</html>
```

You can set the cookie in your browser, or create a login page, where when users login, their browser will have password stored in their cookie.